# Deleting a class without IDE

Tags: apex, production, sdlc

Salesforce makes it hard to delete classes in a production org.  Our change control policy doesn't allow for the use of the IDE to make changes to the production org...everything goes through change sets for traceability to th original request.

How do I delete a class?

Comment: This is a good question, and the answer applies not only to classes, but visual force pages, triggers etc.

Comment: There isn't a way (currently) to delete classes or triggers in a production instance without a developer tool (like the Force.com IDE or the Force.com Migration Tool).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can be done with the Force.com Migration Tool: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool

See the full documentation here: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool

The tool can create or delete any meta-data that can be created through the Force.com IDE or Change Sets.  It comes with a sample config file that contains example deployments for deploying objects and Apex code and deleting them as well.  The documentation has a very detailed step-by-step guide here: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/forcemigrationtool.htm

Comment: I like this answer for your change control process, because you can build a structured process around it (i.e., keeping destructiveChange files in version control, review of files prior to use, only building from immutable tags of the files, etc.) around it.

Comment: This is still a developer tool, and using it does not provide the traceability/logging the original poster needs.

Comment: It's easily traceable by keeping a history of your deployment files.  If they have a change control system they generally have methods of tracking ANT-style deployments or scripts used for deploying.  Even the Force.com IDE will allow you to create zip files of your deployment so you can keep a history of what has been done.

Comment: I guess sometimes you get your question answered but just don't like the answer.  :)